# how to set UIimageview width with respect to the original image size ratio

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

In my iphone app i need to set image in the image view.

**the image view height is always 100pixels.**

**`we need to set the width of the image view with respect to the original image scale ratio.`**

ie per suppose width X height of an image is **300x400 (original) (4x3)**

our displayed image view image size would be **75X100**

width X height of an image is **512x512 (original) (1x1)**

our displayed image view image size would be **100X100**

width X height of an image is **128 x 256 (original) (1x2)**

our displayed image view image size would be **50X100**

*`in all those cases image view height 100pixel should be same, but the width need to varie with respect to the image ratio.`*

And finally **the image view should be in center of the view**

How to achieve it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can achieve this. The simplest is to set the scaling mode on the image view to Aspect Fill in Interface Builder, or

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

The second way is to calculate the aspect ratio of the image and set the width.  Something like:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage"];
float aspectRatio = myImage.size.width / myImage.size.height;
float viewWidth = 100 * aspectRatio;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well Its up to your logics. 
You can get `UIImage` height and width.

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImage.png"];
 float imageHeight = image.size.height;
 float imageWidth = image.size.width;
```

After that you can calculate imageViewWidth-.
**According to your requirement -**

```
float value = imageHeight/100.0;
float iV_Width = imageWidth/value;
```